AWS S3 website using CloudFront has too many redirects
I have a S3 bucket configured as a website, mysite.net.
Another empty bucket named www.mysite.net, the website for this bucket is not enabled.
I have a hosted zone in Route53 for mysite.net
There are two A records (www.mysite.net and mysite.net) pointing to my Distribution domain name.
An NS and SOA record for mysite.net
Two CNAME records for my certificate.
My Cloudfront distribution is configured with alternate domain names www.mysite.net and mysite.net.
Supporting HTTP.
My SSL certificate has been verified.
When attempting to visit my site I get errors stating "Too Many Redirects"
I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

Try curl -I -L <your-website> to get a full breakdown of the request path.  -I includes the response headers, and -L will follow the redirects individually.  This should at least help you understand where the loop is coming from.
